# refers to the inverse side field which does not exist. Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working on a OneToOne join in doctrine2/symphony 2.8.2 and I keep getting:

```
The association X\BaseDesignBundle\Entity\SessionDesign#user refers to the inverse side field X\UserBundle\Entity\User#SessionDesign which does not exist.
```

User:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="X\BaseDesignBundle\Entity\SessionDesign")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fcid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $sessionDesign;
```

Session Design:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="x\UserBundle\Entity\User")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="fcid")
*/
private $user;
```

I have 0 idea whats wrong at this point and I have tried everything I can think of. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Try validating schema via console command `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`. It should give you some clues.

Have you tried deleting cache?

Try renaming `$sessionDesign` to `$SessionDesign`. What happens?

Comment: doctrine:schema:validate - Fails. I get: 

The referenced column name 'fcid' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'x\UserBundle\Entity\User'.


Deleting the cache doesn't do anything. Changing the case does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

JoinColumn should only appear on the entity where the FK is.

E.g (assuming FK is on Session Design.)

Session Design

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="X\BaseDesignBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fcid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

User:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="x\UserBundle\Entity\SessionDesign", inversedBy="user")
*/
private $sessionDesign;
```

For your own sanity I would recommend naming your FK better. fcid doesn't mean much at a glance, why not call it user_id or session_design_id (depending on where you put the FK).

E.g. `* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="session_design_id", referencedColumnName="id")`

It just makes things easier to parse

See the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately I've been trying that every which way. I'm wondering if it's the actual database at this point.

Comment: There's no reason that shouldn't work, and your original example is definitely wrong. I'd try removing the FK (it may be on both tables!!) and re-generating the schema with a correct setup.

Comment: Run a describe on both tables & check the schema is as you'd expect.

Comment: Heres what I get after running doctrine:schema:validate

* The association FYP\FYPDesignBundle\Entity\SessionDesign#productVariant refers to the inverse side field FYP\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductVariant#sessionDesigns which does not exist.
* The referenced column name 'fcid' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'FYP\UserBundle\Entity\User'.

Comment: That looks like a different entity throwing an error now. Most likely a OneToMany. Check the documentation and ensure you have that relation correct.

Comment: I tried a OneToMany but the relationship is a OneToOne. Regardless of that I still got the same error. Is there a way to declare a foreign key in doctrine? The sql (tested in phpmyadmin) it spits out works fine but doctrine doesn't want to execute it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104457/discussion-between-jeremy-and-richard).

Answer (score 0):

I would add to previous answer:
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="X\BaseDesignBundle\Entity\User", **mappedBy="sessionDesign"**)